# Call to undefined method DB_Error::fetchInto

Tags: php, mysql

How to fix this error? Thank you.

update my question

the error on line 22 is

```
<?php while( $res->fetchInto( $row,DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC ) ) { ?>
```

my page code is

```
<?php
  // Install the DB module using 'pear install DB'
  require_once( "db.php" );

  $data = array();

  $db =& DB::connect("mysql://root@localhost/srdp", array());
  if (PEAR::isError($db)) { die($db->getMessage()); }

  $res = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY last" );
  ?>
  <html>
  <body>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>First</th>
  <th>Middle</th>
  <th>Last</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <?php while( $res->fetchInto( $row,DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC ) ) { ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo( $row['No_KP'] ); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo( $row['Nama'] ); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo( $row['middle'] ); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo( $row['last'] ); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo( $row['email'] ); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  </table>
  Download as an 
  <a href="listxl.php">Excel spreadsheet</a>.
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: have you properly installed the DB package? `pear install DB`?

Comment: ya...i have install already

Comment: take a look on the link http://pear.php.net/package/DB its superseded

Comment: That means `$res` is an object of the class `DB_Error`. That sounds like the query was wrong. I have no experience with the `DB` package, but it seems like you should be careful what `$db->query` returns and not automatically assume it was a success.